# Passing data through Angular2 router

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I have a component where I select a set of image objects. I want to pass these selected images to my new route, CreateAlbum. The data it nested and wouldn't be suitable to pass as URL parameters.

Is there any easy way to achieve this?

Here's my code to navigate to the route

```
  public gotoCreateAlbum(): void {
    this.router.navigate([('/create-album')])
  }
```

My selected data sits in this variable

```
@Input() selectedPhotos: IPhoto[];
```

and this is my routing module

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'photos',  component: PhotosComponent},
  { path: 'photos/:filter', component: PhotosComponent},
  { path: 'create-album', component: CreateAlbumComponent}
];
```

Basically I want to perform the same operations as if the CreateAlbum component was a child to my current component in which case I would have used @Input()

Comment: Use a shared service https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: Thanks for that. Works perfect. Would wish they had a data input variable to a routerlink though

Comment: A routerLink can only provide what the URL bar can provide. What also might work is https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#resolve-guard but that also doesn't take arguments from the routerLink except route parameters and other stuff that the URL bar supports.

Comment: Best I found on internet for this is https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-navigation-with-data

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See https://angular.io/guide/router for an in-depth example. Scroll down to this code snippet:

```
gotoHeroes(hero: Hero) {
  let heroId = hero ? hero.id : null;
  // Pass along the hero id if available
  // so that the HeroList component can select that hero.
  // Include a junk 'foo' property for fun.
  this.router.navigate(['/heroes', { id: heroId, foo: 'foo' }]);
}
```

To get the value of 'id' in the target component:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.heroes$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
    switchMap((params: ParamMap) => {
      // (+) before `params.get()` turns the string into a number
      this.selectedId = +params.get('id');
      return this.service.getHeroes();
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: how do you receive the data?

Comment: @Philip Beber Why you have used `switchMap` here

Comment: Because this.service.getHeroes() executes asynchronously and returns an observable. If it executed synchronously and returned a plain value then you would use map(). switchmap is cool because it cancels any operations you no longer care about. For example, say this.route.paramMap.pipe() emits a value, then this.service.getHeroes() will be called and an observable created. When this.route.paramMap.pipe() emits another value that observable will be canceled and its resources releases. this.service.getHeroes() is called again and a new observable created.

Answer (score 26):

I hope this will work. Try using Query Parameters.

```
 <nav>
      <a [routerLink]="['/component1']">No param</a>
      <a [routerLink]="['/component2']" [queryParams]="{ page: 99 }">Go to Page 99</a>
 </nav>
```

or

```
opencomponent2(pageNum) {
    this.router.navigate(['/component2'], { queryParams: { page: pageNum } });
  }
```

In child component :

```
constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route
      .queryParams
      .subscribe(params => {
        // Defaults to 0 if no query param provided.
        this.page = +params['page'] || 0;
      });
  }
```

I have studied this on rangle.io website. Try this if it works for you. 
otherwise https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service is only option.

Comment: What if you want to pass object? `pageNum:{"name":"John"}`

Comment: @dev same for me, have you find any solution ?

Comment: Maybe you can avoid object. For multiple params you can do `this.router.navigate(['/Component2'], { queryParams: { page: 3, otherpage:4 } });`

Answer (score 2):

Unless you want users to manipulate the query string in the addressbar, do a "atob" and "btoa" before sending and after receiving the data. Just a little 
security

Also, if you don't want to have a subscription, you can use the Route snapshot param as follows (just that it doesn't keep on updating like an observable, so unless the component gets re-init, it won't be getting updated value if any. Hence a good place to get the value is in the ngOnInit event handler

```
// before
this._router.navigate(["/welcome/" + atob(userName)]);

// after
ngOnInit() {
    this.userName = btoa(this.route.snapshot.params['userName']);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass data using  router, for example

```
{ path: 'form', component: FormComponent ,data :{data :'Test Data'} },
```

and your component

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

export class FormComponent {
    sub: any;
    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.sub = this.route
            .data
            .subscribe(value => console.log(value));
    }
}
```

[More info](http://www.angulartutorial.net/2017/12/angular-24-routing-with-simple-examples.html)

But this may not be the preferred way, `you can use parent child communication or make a service common and share data between them`. Check below references for doing that.

[Parent child communication](http://www.angulartutorial.net/2017/10/communicate-with-parent-and-child.html)

[Share data using service](http://www.angulartutorial.net/2017/09/angular-share-data-between-components.html)

Comment: how do you dynamically pass the data? i.e using this.route.navigate()

Answer (score 1):

```
sender html

<a [routerLink]="['../../../print/attendance/',{data:userDetails | json}]">link</a>

receiver ts
ngOnInit() {
   this.route.params.subscribe(params=>
    {
      this.data=JSON.parse(params['data'])
    }
    );

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`Angular >= 7.2.0` introduced a new way of passing the data when navigating between routed components. In `NavigationExtras` interface within the router module was added a new attribute: `state: any` and you can set the data which will be present in the new state.

#### In component

```js
export class ComponentA {
    constructor(private router: Router) {}

    goToComponentB(): void {
        // programmatically        
        this.router.navigate(['/b'], {state: {data: {...}}});
    }
}
```

#### In HTML

```html
<a routerLink="/b" [state]="{ data: {...}}">Go to B</a>
```

#### Get data in Component B using `history.state.data`

```
export class ComponentB {
    constructor() {
       console.log(history.state.data); // GET DATA
    }
}
```

Thanks to `Ľudovít Hajzer` Read the whole blog here https://medium.com/ableneo/how-to-pass-data-between-routed-components-in-angular-2306308d8255

Answer (score -1):

```
this.router.navigate(['path', { flag: "1"}]);
```