# How to pass arbitrary (non parameterized) data to a route in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing, angular-router

*First : it's not a dup. The linked dup question's answer uses service which i'm not after it.*

I have a routing table :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  ...
  { path: 'comp1', loadChildren: './module1/module1.module.ts#Module1Module' },
  ...
  ];
```

In the main component's ctor  ( `app.component.ts`) i'm navigating to :

```
constructor(private router: Router){
  router.navigate(['/comp1',{aaa:222,bbb:{ccc:3}}])
}
```

However - it is serialized to a URL.

> https://angular-iqfnre-router.stackblitz.io/comp1;aaa=222;bbb=%5Bobject%20Object%5D

Now - I don't want it to appear in url. (not to mention that the value is not valid)

Also - the remote route in the lazy module is :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: Comp1Component,

    children: [{
      path: 'acomp', component: AComponent,
    }]

  }
];
```

So it doesn't support parameters ( and i'm not talking about parameter but a complex data).

I don't want to change the route table.

**Question:**

How can I pass arbitrary (complex) data to the route - and how can I read it once i'm after routed ?

[**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iqfnre-router?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

**NB**

**I don't want to use a service**. I'm sure that there is another option to load the route with data. The [docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#query-parameters-and-fragments) mentioned  `NavigationExtras` But I think it's still using URL. 
(please - no stringify).

Comment: OK I’ll remove the flag after your edit

Comment: Removed the first comment

Comment: So I read the documentation about the your specific goal and what I understand is that all the available options are enhancements or different options of sending data through the query parameters. So I don’t think it’s possible to achieve what you want, at least the non inclusion on the url

Comment: @HugoNoro :-( well I can stringify it - but that's ugly. anyway - I'll keep waiting. :) thanks

Comment: Nonetheless at least might seem an interesting challenge. I’ll read about it and let you know if I find a solution

Comment: @HugoNoro Thanks !( btw can u plz remove the dup  flag? )

Comment: I thought I did already. Don’t think I have enough privileges for that. But don’t worry it will be dismissed when they moderate it and check the comments.

Comment: You want to use the router, but don't want it to appear in the url. Right? If that is the case, use a service as there is no benefit using the router.

Comment: @yuruzi Can you have a look ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of requirements I would suggest using a shared service. With that you can pass the type of data you want without causing any additional overhead on the route.

Comment: Yes with services I can do everything. But I'm sure that it is supported. Also - when I think about it - If i pass a value to the service - this value should be awaited to be read by the target component.

Comment: When you use DI of the service from parent to child, the same instance gets injected on both parent and child so the data will be available immediately. Not sure why you say it would need to wait.

Comment: Example : Im in A and want to go to B with extra data D. so in A im doing `.navigate(["B"]`. but before that I'll have to invoke a service with data D with slot S1. now  - after navigated to B - B will ahve to read (inject) the service and read value S1. That's not complicated but not as simple as oveloading the route with additional data ( which i'm sure can be done).

Comment: I understand your idea and I can see your point. But I’m not sure you’ll be able to do it since all the navigation extras are basically ways of manipulating query parameters.

Comment: Does it have to be on the routerLink level? Or can it be set on the route config stage?

Comment: Link level. (optional data). in js it is possible to do `function foo(){}; foo.baa = 1`. I jsut need the shared object to attach data to it.

Comment: You’re not making it easy :)

Comment: Check this answer. I don’t think you can achieve what you need. Router link only supports whatever the url address bar supports https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41039870/passing-data-through-angular2-router

Comment: I can assure you that there is an option. All we need is that shared `foo` to put `foo.data`. I'll wait for other answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Havn't had a chance to fully test this but seems to work on a simple route 
altho currently it stringify's the object which isn't the best.

In a global component/service add

```
let routeData = null;
    this.router.events
          .filter((event) => (event instanceof ActivationStart || event instanceof ActivationEnd)).subscribe((event) => {

            if (event instanceof ActivationStart) {
              if(event.snapshot.params) {
                let routeDataStr:string = event.snapshot.params.routeData;

                if (routeDataStr) {
                  routeData = JSON.parse(routeDataStr);
                  if (event.snapshot.url[0]) {
                    this.router.navigate([event.snapshot.url[0].path]);
                  }
                }
              }
            } else if (event instanceof ActivationEnd) {

              let actEnd:ActivationEnd = event;

              if (routeData) {
                actEnd.snapshot.data = actEnd.snapshot.data == null ? {} : actEnd.snapshot.data;
                actEnd.snapshot.data.routeData = routeData
              }
            }
          })
```

Then to trigger the navigation use

```
let dataob:DataObject = {
  blah: 123
}
this.router.navigate(['/comp1', {routeData: JSON.stringify(dataob)}]);
```

On the component that you just navigated to you can now access the data on the activeRoute

```
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.route.snapshot.data.routeData)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

See the "Passing static data to a route" section in https://yakovfain.com/2015/11/11/angular-2-passing-data-to-routes:

> #### Passing static data to a route
>
> While most of the times parent components will be passing data to
>   their children, Angular also offers a mechanism to pass additional
>   data to components at the time of the route configuration. For
>   example, besides the dynamic data like product ID we may need to pass
>   a flag indicating if the application runs in production environment or
>   not. This can be done by using the data property of your route
>   configuration. For example, our route for the product details can be
>   configured as follows:
>
> ```
> {path: 'product/:id', component: ProductDetailComponentParam ,
>                       data: [{isProd: true}]}
> ```
>
> The data property can contain an array of arbitrary string key-values
>   pairs. When the router will open ProductDetailComponentParam the data
>   value will be located in the data property of the
>   ActivatedRoute.snapshot:
>
> ```
> export class ProductDetailComponentParam {
>   productID: string;
>   isProdEnvironment: string;
>
>   constructor(route: ActivatedRoute) {
>     this.productID = route.snapshot.params['id'];
>
>     this.isProdEnvironment = route.snapshot.data[0]['isProd'];
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> Passing data to a route via the data property is not an alternative to
>   configuring parameters in the path property as in *path: ‘product/:id’*
>   but can come handy when you need to pass some data to a route during
>   the configuration phase, e.g. is it a production or QA environment.

Comment: That's not what i wanted. your solution provides a global infor for the route. I want to send a specific info when I navigate.

Comment: I dont knbow if it will fit in your use case or not but I think then you can use skipLocationChange property which will load the child view silently without pushing a new state into route history, so it will keep the url same and also you can pass additional data .

`this.router.navigate(['/view'], { skipLocationChange: true });`